# Time complexity of quadratic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

For my exam of programming and algorithm design I have to be familiar with time complexity and the Big-Oh notation. I understand most of it, but then I bumped in to this question and the solution I have seems fairly simple; but I don't understand which steps are necessary. Could someone clarify the steps took?

Exercise:

> A quadratic algorithm with processing time T(n) = cn^2 spends T(N) seconds for processing N data items. How much time will be spent for processing n = 3000 data items, assuming that N = 100 and T (N) = 1 ms?

Given solution:

> The constant factor c = T(N)/(N^2), therefore T(n) = T(N) * (n^2)/(N^2) = n^2/10000 and
>       T (3000) = 900 ms

Comment: I'm totally confused with `n` and `N`. both are the count of data items but they differ.

Comment: N and n looks the same thing. I think N is used to represent a particular example.

Comment: really? "How much time will be spent for processing n = 3000 data items, assuming that N = 100"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple maths problem, not a specific programming problem.

Comment: The exam question is poorly worded.  The 'assuming' clause should be clearer, perhaps: _assuming that when N = 100, T(N) = 1 ms_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty simple maths problem:

If `T(n) = cn²` and `T(100) = 1ms` then

```
T(100) = c * 100²
       = c * 10,000
       = 1ms
```

Therefore solving for `c` gives:

```
c = (1/10,000)ms
```

This can then be used to calculate `T(3000)`:

```
T(3000) = (1/10,000)ms * 3,000²
        = (1/10,000)ms * 9,000,000
        = (9,000,000 / 10,000)ms
        = 900ms
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was just looking the wrong way ... Haha, thanks a lot ! *blushy face*

Answer (score 1):

It is straight forward. You have `N = 100`, `T(N) = 1`. So `c = T(N)/N^2 = 1/10000`.

Then you do `T(3000) = 1/10000 * (3000 ^ 2) = 900`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with Big-Oh notation, or even computer science. All you need is basic algebra. Given that T(n) = cn^2 for some c, and T(100) = 0.001, what is T(3000)?

```
    0.001 = T(100) = c (100*100) = 10000c
    c = 10^-7

    T(3000) = c n^2 = 10^-7 * 3000 * 3000 = 0.9
```